# How to change the font size in the 'The requested content cannot be loaded' error message and make it bold?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

How can I change the font size in the `The requested content cannot be loaded` error message and make it bold? I can't Find anything on this on the web.

Is there a way to replace the `error` message with a link to something else? Is a way to disable it?

I think that I know were the line of code is to edit but I don't know how to edit it

```
tmp.html( '<p id="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br />Please try again later.</p>' );
```

Comment: I think that I know were the line of code is..to edit but I don't know how to edit it.. tmp.html( '<p id="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be
loaded.<br />Please try again later.</p>' );

Comment: Have you researched CSS at all? Or read the [fancybox documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto)?

Comment: I have read about html and CSS and tried somethings and it didn't work, why do you think that Im asking...

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran : about your comment `You doesn't seem to be good enough to get help yet.` ... I would rather say : "you (Jonas) don't seem to be good enough to help others yet"

Comment: @JFK This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful.

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran not for you, that's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fancybox **v2.x**, you can use the `tpl` API option to set a new *class* and content error message like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        tpl: {
            error: '<p class="fancybox-error myError">this is my new error message: found <i>nothing</i></p>'
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** I added the *class* `myError` to the template. Then you can add your own css rules for that *class* like

```
.myError {
    font-family: trebuchet ms, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #880000;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q3ovw6w4/)** (v2.x)

For fancybox **v1.3.4**,  an easier and simpler option is to set a new error `content` using the (undocumented) `onError` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        onError: function () {
            var errorMsg = "This is my new error mesage";
            $.fancybox("<p class='myError'>" + errorMsg + "</p>");
            return false;
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

You still need to declare your own css rules for the selector `.myError` as for v2.x example.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8fcmtsx1/)** (v1.3.4)

Comment: Is there a way to replace the error message with a link to something else?